# Lock around lambda event handler

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda

I need to synchronize a sequence of operations that contains an asynchronous part.
The method looks into an image cache and returns the image if it's there (invokes a callback in reality). Otherwise it has to download it from the server. The download operation is asynchronous and fires an event on completion.

This is the (simplified) code.

```
private Dictionary<string, Bitmap> Cache;

public void GetImage(string fileName, Action<Bitmap> onGetImage)
{
    if (Cache.ContainsKey(fileName))
    {
        onGetImage(Cache[fileName]);
    }
    else
    {
        var server = new Server();
        server.ImageDownloaded += server_ImageDownloaded;
        server.DownloadImageAsync(fileName, onGetImage); // last arg is just passed to the handler
    }
}

private void server_ImageDownloaded(object sender, ImageDownloadedEventArgs e)
{
    Cache.Add(e.Bitmap, e.Name);
    var onGetImage = (Action<Bitmap>)e.UserState;
    onGetImage(e.Bitmap);
}
```

The problem: if two threads call GetImage almost at the same time, they will both call the server and try to add the same image to the cache. What I should do is create lock at the beginning of GetImage and release it at the end of the server_ImageDownloaded handler.

Obviously this is not doable with the `lock` construct and it would not make sense, because it would be difficult to ensure that the lock is realeased in any case.

Now what I thought I could do is use a lambda instead of the event handler. This way I can put a lock around the whole section:

I have to lock the Cache dictionary at the beginning of the DownloadImage method and release it only at the end of the ImageDownloaded event handler.

```
private Dictionary<string, Bitmap> Cache;

public void GetImage(string fileName, Action<Bitmap> onGetImage)
{
    lock(Cache)
    {
        if (Cache.ContainsKey(fileName))
        {
            onGetImage(Cache[fileName]);
        }
        else
        {
            var server = new Server();
            server.ImageDownloaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                Cache.Add(e.Bitmap, e.Name);
                onGetImage(e.Bitmap);
            }
            server.DownloadImageAsync(fileName, onGetImage); // last arg is just passed to the handler
        }
    }
}
```

Is this safe? Or the lock is immediately released after execution of GetImage, leaving the lambda expression unlocked?

Is there a better approach to solve this problem?

---

**SOLUTION**

In the end the solution was a bit of a mix of all the answers and comments, unfortunately I cannot mark-as-answer all of them. So here is my final code (removed some null checks/error cases/etc. for clarity).

```
private readonly object ImageCacheLock = new object();
private Dictionary<Guid, BitmapImage> ImageCache { get; set; }
private Dictionary<Guid, List<Action<BitmapImage>>> PendingHandlers { get; set; }

public void GetImage(Guid imageId, Action<BitmapImage> onDownloadCompleted)
{
    lock (ImageCacheLock)
    {
        if (ImageCache.ContainsKey(imageId))
        {
            // The image is already cached, we can just grab it and invoke our callback.
            var cachedImage = ImageCache[imageId];
            onDownloadCompleted(cachedImage);
        }
        else if (PendingHandlers.ContainsKey(imageId))
        {
            // Someone already started a download for this image: we just add our callback to the queue.
            PendingHandlers[imageId].Add(onDownloadCompleted);
        }
        else
        {
            // The image is not cached and nobody is downloading it: we add our callback and start the download.
            PendingHandlers.Add(imageId, new List<Action<BitmapImage>>() { onDownloadCompleted });
            var server = new Server();
            server.DownloadImageCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
            server.DownloadImageAsync(imageId);
        }
    }
}

private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, ImageDownloadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Action<BitmapImage>> handlersToExecute = null;
    BitmapImage downloadedImage = null;

    lock (ImageCacheLock)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // ...
            ImageCache.Add(e.imageId, e.bitmap);
            downloadedImage = e.bitmap;
        }

        // Gets a reference to the callbacks that are waiting for this image and removes them from the waiting queue.
        handlersToExecute = PendingHandlers[imageId];
        PendingHandlers.Remove(imageId);
    }

    // If the download was successful, executes all the callbacks that were waiting for this image.
    if (downloadedImage != null)
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlersToExecute)
            handler(downloadedImage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just keep a a collection of image filenames that are being downloaded, and have the code for a thread be:

```
public void GetImage(string fileName, Action<Bitmap> onGetImage) 
{ 
    lock(Cache) 
    { 
        if (Cache.ContainsKey(fileName)) 
        { 
            onGetImage(Cache[fileName]); 
        } 
        else if (downloadingCollection.contains(fileName))
        {
            while (!Cache.ContainsKey(fileName))
            {
                System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(Cache)
            }
            onGetImage(Cache[fileName]); 
        }
        else 
        { 
           var server = new Server(); 
           downloadCollection.Add(filename);
           server.ImageDownloaded += (s, e) => 
           { 
              lock (Cache)
              {
                  downloadCollection.Remove(filename);
                  Cache.Add(e.Bitmap, e.Name); 
                  System.Threading.Monitor.PulseAll(Cache);
              }
              onGetImage(e.Bitmap);

           } 
           server.DownloadImageAsync(fileName, onGetImage); // last arg is just passed to the handler 
        } 
    } 
}
```

That is more or less the standard monitor pattern, or would be if you refactored the lambda expression into a member function like `GetImage`. You should really do that. It will make the monitor logic easier to reason about.

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good idea. Jon's solution (in the last comment) is a slightly more refined variation of this pattern, but the basic idea is on the same line.

Comment: And if the other thread that's downloading the filename fails, this code is going to wait forever.  And any other thread that wants to download that file is going to wait forever.

Comment: updated the original question with the final solution where this should not happen.

Answer (score 2):

The lambda expression is converted into a delegate within a lock, but the *body* of the lambda expression will *not* automatically acquire the lock for the `Cache` monitor when the delegate is executed. So you *may* want:

```
server.ImageDownloaded += (s, e) =>
{
    lock (Cache)
    {
        Cache.Add(e.Bitmap, e.Name);
    }
    onGetImage(e.Bitmap);
}
```

Comment: (WOW, that was fast!) This makes sense and is what I suspected. However having two separate lock sections will not solve the problem because the time waiting for the async operation to complete is "unprotected". Suppose the server call is /very/ slow and several threads call the method with the same arguments: they will all find the cache empty and perform the remote call. What I need to achieve is to effectively make this operation (as a whole) sequential.

Comment: Forgot to add: obviously a Monitor.Enter/Exit would work, but I was trying to avoid that as it looks a bit risky with a remote invocation in the middle. (maybe the feeling is wrong though)

Comment: @Francesco: Depending on your platform, just don't use an async call. If you *have* to use an async call, you'll need to work a bit harder, e.g. have some list of "currently running requests" etc.

Comment: @Jon Unfortunately I have no choice as this is a Silverlight web service, which can only be asynchronous (as of version 4). I suppose I'll just carefully analyze the code and use a Monitor.

Comment: @Francesco: I would try not to - there's a reason why the asynchrony is encouraged. You may want to have a cache and a map of "pending handlers" - so that the second request can add itself to that map, and the first response can call the second request's handler when it completes... all without the second method call blocking for the duration of the fetch.

Comment: That's a very good idea, thanks! It's slightly more refined than @Kevin's solution, but I suppose you won't mind if I give him the points ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have another potential problem here.  This code:

```
if (Cache.ContainsKey(fileName))
{
    onGetImage(Cache[fileName]);
}
```

If some other thread removes the image from the cache after your call to `ContainsKey` but before the next line is executed, it's going to crash.

If you're using `Dictionary` in a multi-threaded context where concurrent threads can be reading and writing, then you need to protect *every access* with a lock of some kind.  `lock` is convenient, but [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) will provide better performance.

I would also suggest that you re-code the above to be:

```
Bitmap bmp;
if (Cache.TryGetValue(fileName, out bmp))
{
    onGetImage(fileName);
}
```

If you're running .NET 4.0, then I would strongly suggest that you look into using [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I considered this and concluded it was safe in this particular case because there is no way to remove items from the cache. The only way to clear the cache is to replace the whole object that includes it.

Comment: But it's not safe. It's possible that another thread adding an item will cause the backing array to be resized, which can move items around. If another thread is trying to access the dictionary at the same time, you can end up getting back the wrong item. You MUST prevent concurrent reads and updates. Multiple readers is okay, but updates must have exclusive access.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that! ConcurrentDictionary is not part of Silverlight, fortunately the final implementation (a map of pending handlers all executed when the first download is completed) allows me to keep any access to the cache inside a lock, so any update is synchronized.